# Angular Material Progresbar is not shown/hidden with *ngif

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, jspdf

I have an application where the webpage need to display a progress bar while website fetech data from several APIs and construct a pdf document.Here I use `jsPDF` to construct the pdf. I used following implementation in my template.

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
<mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate" [value]="progressValue" *ngIf="isPrintinginProgress"></mat-progress-bar>
<Button class="btn btn-primary" style="align: right" (click)="printSelected()">Print Selected</Button></div>
```

`isPrintinginProgress` variable is initialized at the beginning to hideout the element and is updated to true at the `printSelected()` function to show the element.

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';

export class PrintViewComponent implements OnInit {
  printList: PrintPendingOrderModel[];
  isPrintinginProgress = false;   

  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<PrintPendingOrderModel>(this.printList);
  selection = new SelectionModel<PrintPendingOrderModel>(true, []);

  constructor(private apiService: ApisService,
          private utilService: UtilsService) { }
  ngOnInit() {


  }
   printSelected() {
     this.isPrintinginProgress = true; //showing up the progressbar         
     const doc = new jsPDF();    
     console.log('printing page:', page_no); 
     if (page_no < total_pages) {
        console.log('end page:', page_no);        
        doc.addPage();
     } else {
        doc.autoPrint({variant: 'non-conform'});        
        window.open(doc.output('bloburl'), '_blank').focus();
        console.log('Print Complete');       
        this.isPrintinginProgress = false; //hiding up the progressbar
     }
     this.selection.clear();
   }
```

}
    }

If I initialize `isPrintinginProgress` to true the progressbar is shown at the beginning but value change in the `isPrintinginProgress` variable is not reflected in the elements functionality using `*ngif(show/hide)`

Comment: Looks like it might throwing error in console that stopping execution of setting it false. Try to put false condition in starting of else block.

Comment: Is it going in else condition only, could you check it once.

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: No errors in the console. And yes it's executed in the printSelected() Method only. And changing to starting block didn't make any change

Comment: If I comment up the this.isPrintinginProgress = false; the progress bar is shown after the new window opens with the constructed pdf, may be jsPdf blocks up changes in the template?

Comment: can you run npm install again and try?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1

```
<div *ngIf="isPrintinginProgress" class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
<mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate" [value]="progressValue" ></mat-progress-bar>
</div>
<Button class="btn btn-primary" style="align: right" (click)="printSelected()">Print Selected</Button>
```

Create a div on which you have the progress bar and the div may be hidden or shown using ngIf coniditon.

Option 2

```
<div [hidden]="!isPrintinginProgress" class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
<mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate" [value]="progressValue" ></mat-progress-bar>
</div>
<Button class="btn btn-primary" style="align: right" (click)="printSelected()">Print Selected</Button>
```

You may also use the [hidden] attribute to hide and show.

Comment: Tried, both option no change, somehow the template won't recognize the changes to the variable.

Comment: Can you put up the code on SlackBliz so that it would be come easier to try.

Comment: Is the variable isPrintinginProgress changing it value from true to false or viceversa?

Comment: yes variable values are changed on the execution that works well, only thing is it won't display on the template.

Comment: Can you put the code on StackBlitz so that a solution may be worked out

Comment: sure. I'll add in StackBlitz

Answer (score 0):

It might possible the changes isn't detected. Try below code once.

```
constructor( private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef){
}

this.isPrintinginProgress = false;
this.cdr.detectChanges();
```

Comment: Added this, no changes.

Answer (score 0):

Note: If in your console you are getting `Print Complete` then your flag is changing quickly so you can't notice the change. Trying putting timeout.

```
printSelected() {
 this.isPrintinginProgress = true; //showing up the progressbar         
 this.setTimeout(()=>{
 const doc = new jsPDF();    
     console.log('printing page:', page_no); 
     if (page_no < total_pages) {
        console.log('end page:', page_no);        
        doc.addPage();
     } else {
        doc.autoPrint({variant: 'non-conform'});        
        window.open(doc.output('bloburl'), '_blank').focus();
        console.log('Print Complete');       
        this.isPrintinginProgress = false; //hiding up the progressbar
     }
 this.selection.clear();
 },3000);
}
```

Comment: Actually it takes sometime to Print Complete and the window seems frozen for that time.