# Why *ngIF is not working in Cordova Angular?

Tags: android, angular, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have been stucked in this for a while. It is confirm that **this.progressBarValue** is changed to true. But the progress bar is not displaying. Can someone help me with this thanks in advance.

some-component.html

```
<div class="progressBar">
  <mat-progress-bar class="fileProgress" mode="indeterminate" *ngIf="progressBarValue">
  </mat-progress-bar>
</div>
```

some-component.ts

```
confirmConversion() {
this.progressBarValue = true;
console.log(this.progressBarValue)
var filepath = this.filePath;
var fileextension = this.settingsExtension;
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  window.ConvertMedia(filepath, fileextension, resolve, reject);
}).then((message) => {
  console.log(message);
});}
```

It is working(Progress bar is displayed) if I don't call that Cordova API. 
I also tried this using some methods given below but it didn't worked.

```
this.zone.run(() => this.progressBarValue = true)
  console.log(this.progressBarValue)

this.changeDetector.detectChanges() & this.changeDetector.markForCheck()
```

**Note:** ProgressBar is displayed if I update this.progressBar = true inside

```
.then((message) => {console.log(message);});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to add *ngIf to container - div like that:

```
<div class="progressBar" *ngIf="progressBarValue">
  <mat-progress-bar class="fileProgress" mode="indeterminate">
  </mat-progress-bar>
</div>
```

If default value for progressBarValue is false mat-progress-bar could not load properly.

Write if it helps or still nothing ;)

Also you can add to your html code
eg. :

```
<span> {{progressBarValue}} </span>
```

to keep track of value and be sure if it's even changing

Comment: Thanks and Sorry for the delay. I tried <span> {{progressBarValue}} </span> Yeah you are true the value is not updated, But I checked using console.log() The value of progressBarValue is changed as expected. Even though after trying what you said I couldn't accomplish it until I remove the API(window.convertMedia()). Is there any other way to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks if you are checking into this again. But this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59260981/14030226) helped me.

Comment: what was the problem after all? Variable didn't update or you had to hide div with css/some other property?

Comment: Yeah I had to hide a div which is with with this id (progressBarValue)